# Do they all have the same meaning: "to go uneaten" vs "to get uneaten" vs "to be uneaten"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, idiomatic-language, passive-voice

This is from the BBC.

“Don’t be afraid to cut out elements you’re not keen on. **If bread sauce always goes uneaten, don’t make it."**

**"to go uneaten"** sounds interesting to me. And it seems to have the same meaning as these grammatical structures:

"If bread sauce **is always left uneaten**,......" (passive simple present)

"If bread sauce **gets uneaten**, .........."(passive with get)

Is it really the same as the above structures in terms of meaning?

Comment: Don't use "get ___", especially "get (past participle)", unless you are very certain of its use.  Overuse of *get* is a hallmark of English learners.

Comment: Get rich as fast as you can, I say.  Or see Bob Dylan: Subterranean Homesick Blues for a few, well-placed uses of get. And remember, he got the Nobel Prize for Literature and that song is one of his most well-known ones. [Working-class AmE)

Answer (score 6):

They're not all the same.

The original has the structure: *[ "go" + adjective ]*. It means something like, *to remain in a certain condition*.

The passive voice with "leave", *[ "be left" + adjective ]*, has very similar meaning. The nuanced difference is that this version gives agency to the people who leave it, while in the first version, the item simply remains in that same state.

The version with "get" is bad grammar. *[ "Get + past-participle-form" ]* can mean *[ "become" + adjective ]* or it can form the passive voice. Neither works here.

The bread sauce doesn't *become* uneaten. Rather, it *remains* uneaten.

With the passive voice, the word after "get" must be a verb in the past participle, but "uneaten" is not a verb. You cannot "uneat" bread sauce. "Uneaten" is an adjective only.

You could use "get" with "leave" as in the passive version above though, and have roughly the same meaning:

> ...it gets left uneaten...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, to an English speaker the 3 versions would be understood to mean the same thing. Maybe the third version, **gets uneaten**, sounds a bit odd as you would normally expect the construct **..bread sauce gets eaten with turkey..**.
You might also consider: If bread sauce always **remains** uneaten, don't make it.

Comment: To "get uneaten" is ungrammatical. See my answer.